# how to remove the #prettyphoto from the url

Tags: javascript, jquery, tags, wordpress, prettyphoto

i m using prettyphoto media wordpress plugin(version 3.1.4).
its working fine for me but my problem is that when i click on any image and it opened in lightbox then there is some additional tag in url like:#prettyPhoto[landscaping]/0/ thats why the url looks like:`www.myssite.com/#prettyPhoto[landscaping]/0/`.

how can we remove this extra tag.
here is the code in my jquery.prettyPhoto.js file:

```
function setHashtag(){
        if(typeof theRel == 'undefined') return; // theRel is set on normal calls, it's impossible to deeplink using the API
        location.hash = theRel + '/'+rel_index+'/';
    };

    function clearHashtag(){
        if ( location.href.indexOf('#prettyPhoto') !== -1 ) location.hash = "prettyPhoto";
    }
```

Comment: if someone is using prettyphoto media wordpress plugin then in plugins customization tab setting part you can uncheck the Allow prettyPhoto to update the url to enable deeplinking. [default: true].it will work.

Answer (score 48):

I had the same problem yesterday, and I'm quite sure I found the answer here in stackoverflow... I visited so many websites, forums... so I don't remember where I got the answer exactly.

Anyway, I'm working on Dreamweaver, but I guess the code is similar in WP.

What you gotta do is specify the **deeplinking property as false** when you call prettyPhoto.

This is my code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({
            theme:'light_rounded',
            social_tools:false,
            deeplinking:false,      
    });
});
```

I'm a total noob in js, but I hope this helps :)

Comment: This absolutely helps and this is one way where we can hide the ugly URL and back from any page results in actual uRL rather than a picture popup. This is the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({
          theme: 'light_rounded',
          social_tools: false,
          deeplinking: false
      });
  });
```

use **deeplinking:false** to remove #prettyphoto from url